# Regex to extract part of string between parenthesis

Tags: scala

I have below string and I want to extract only `List((asdf, asdf), (fff,qqq))` from the string, line has many other characters before and after the part I want to extract.

```
some garbage string PARAMS=List((foo, bar), (foo1, bar1)) some garbage string
```

I have tried these regex

```
(?:PARAMS)=(List\((.*?)\))
(?:PARAMS)=(List\(([^)]+)\))
```

but it gives me below output in `group(1)`:

```
List((foo, bar)
```

Comment: You explicitly ask it to match only the first () when you write \(([^)]+)\), didn't you realize it?

Comment: Try [this one](http://regexr.com/3e8kn).

Answer (score 1):

***regex `.*List\((.*)\).*` works***

Using Scala regex and pattern matching together and then split with any of `( , )` and then `group`

regex contains extractors

```
val r = """.*List\((.*)\).*""".r
```

pattern matching using extractor in regex

```
val result = str match {
              case r(value) => value
              case _ => ""
             }
```

Then split using any of `(` or `,` or `)` and then `group`

```
result.split("""[(|,|)]""").filterNot(s => s.isEmpty || s.trim.isEmpty)
.grouped(2)
.toList
.map(pair => (pair(0), pair(1))).toList
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> val str = """some garbage string PARAMS=List((foo, bar), (foo1, bar1)) some garbage string"""
str: String = "some garbage string PARAMS=List((foo, bar), (foo1, bar1)) some garbage string"

scala> val r = """.*List\((.*)\).*""".r
r: util.matching.Regex = .*List\((.*)\).*

scala> val result = str match {
  case r(value) => value
  case _ => ""
  }
result: String = "(foo, bar), (foo1, bar1)"

scala> result.split("""[(|,|)]""").filterNot(s => s.isEmpty || s.trim.isEmpty).grouped(2).toList.map(pair => (pair(0), pair(1))).toList
res46: List[(String, String)] = List(("foo", " bar"), ("foo1", " bar1"))
```